PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "WC_Legacy_API" not found
Wordpress error after upgrading woocommerce plugin version to 9.0.0, see error details below
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "WC_Legacy_API" not found in /home/dettrart/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-api.php:19
I found the details in the cpanel error log file.

Try to update woocommerce to version 9.0.1 (the most recent version while i'm writing this comment).

There are two solutions to this;
1- Rollback the woocommerce plugin to v8.9.3
2- Follow the steps below to reinstall the plugin manually:
i- Delete the woocommerce plugin folder in plugin directory using file manager in your cpanel
ii- Download the plugin zip from the wordpress official plugin site
iii- Upload the zip file to your plugin directory in cpanel and extract the file.
